# ID auto increment for extended class object java

Tags: java, class, extends

Have a problem, my ID auto increment code is not working. ID for object is always 0.
Maybe someone can help me with solving this. Tried different ways, but still not working for me.
For my case I should use Employee class for ID counter. but Im not sure that Im doing correct.

Superclass

```
public class Person {
    public String PersonName;
    public String PersonSurname;

    public Person()
    {
        this.PersonName = "";
        this.PersonSurname = "";
    }
    public Person(String PersonName, String PersonSurname)
    {
        this.PersonName = PersonName;
        this.PersonSurname = PersonSurname;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Person name, surname: "+ this.PersonName + " " + this.PersonSurname;
    }

    public void setPersonName(String PersonName)
    {
        this.PersonName = PersonName;
    }
    public void setPersonSurname(String PersonSurname)
    {
        this.PersonSurname = PersonSurname;
    }

    public String getPersonName()
    {
        return PersonName;
    }
    public String getPersonSurname()
    {
        return PersonSurname;
    }
```

class with id counter

```
public class Employee extends Person {
    private int EmployeeID;
    private static int IdCounter = 0;

    public Employee(){
        super("","");
        EmployeeID = 0;
        this.EmployeeID = IdCounter++;
    }

    public Employee(int EmployeeID, String PersonName, String PersonSurname){
        super(PersonName,PersonSurname);
        this.EmployeeID = IdCounter++;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Person name, surname: " +this.EmployeeID + ". " + this.PersonName + " " + this.PersonSurname;
    }

    public void setEmployeeID(int EmployeeID)
    {
        this.EmployeeID = EmployeeID;
    }

    public int getEmployeeID()
    {
        return EmployeeID;
    }

}
```

my main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] rez) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstDigit = "";
        String secDigit = "";
        Employee CompanyEmployee = new Employee();

        do {

            System.out.println("Please input Name: ");
            firstDigit = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please input Surname: ");
            secDigit = scanner.nextLine();

            CompanyEmployee.setPersonName(firstDigit);
            CompanyEmployee.setPersonSurname(secDigit);

            System.out.println(CompanyEmployee);
        }
        while (!firstDigit.equals("dasd"));
```

Comment: You only create one `Employee`. The ID for that employee is zero. If you want multiple employees with different IDs, create multiple employees (e.g. in the loop).

Comment: Hey Sergey the think is you are increase the employeeId in employee constructor right so it’s only update value when you can the constructor but in your code you don’t call constructor in while loop you just set value by using setter and getter for same object so that employees Id not changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your code like below

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] rez) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstDigit = "";
        String secDigit = "";
        List<Employee> listofemployee = new ArrayList<>();
       
        do {

            Employee companyEmployee = new Employee();

            System.out.println("Please input Name: ");
            firstDigit = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please input Surname: ");
            secDigit = scanner.nextLine();

            companyEmployee.setPersonName(firstDigit);
            companyEmployee.setPersonSurname(secDigit);

            System.out.println(companyEmployee);
            listofemployee.add(companyEmployee);
        }
        while (!firstDigit.equals("dasd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need that EmployeeID variable.

```java
public class Employee extends Person {
    private static int id = 0; //renamed your IdCounter variable to just id

    public Employee(){
        super("","");
        id++;            //will increment every time you construct an object 
    }
    
    public Employee(int EmployeeID, String PersonName, String PersonSurname){
        super(PersonName,PersonSurname);
        id++;            //will increment every time you construct an object
    }
   
  
   public getId(){
       return id;
   }
```

I would advice you to use randomizer for giving an id to you objects, because if you run programm again id filed becomes 0 and new objects will get same id as previous ones

---